# How to correctly understand the monogamy of entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

If the degree of entanglement between qubits A and B is 100% (total entanglement), then neither of them can entangle with qubit C. However, if the entanglement between A and B is partial (say 80%), then either A or B can be partially (20%) entangled with qubit C, or can A and B be partially entangled (10% each) with qubit C?

Comment: The most general way of phrasing it is in terms of entanglement measures, see https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/monogamy-entanglement. Note that not all entanglement measures need to satisfy the constraint mentioned in the above link (depending on your criteria for an entanglement measure, that is).

Comment: @Kenneth Goodenough So I understand correctly, or not?